# null pointer exception, findVidewById

Tags: android

I've tried to call findViewById inside the onCreate func, it always return NULL. By referencing other posts, I have already call findViewById right after setContentview, however, the problem still exists, could you please help?

Thanks

JC

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView text = (TextView) super.findViewById(R.id.myText);
    if (text == null){
        Log.d("onCreate", "TextView is NULL");
        return;
    }

    Button button = (Button) super.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    if (button == null){
        Log.d("onCreate", "Button is NULL");
        return;
    }        

    text.setText("ab");
    button.setText("bc");

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

and in my fragment_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.testapp2.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You are using `activity_main.xml` but shown is `fragment_main.xml'. Are you sure that you are inflating the right one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your views belong to  `fragment_main.xml` in which case you should be initializing views in `Fragment` not in Activity.

You have `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` so `findViewById` looks for a view in the current view hierarchy. Since `activtiy_main.xml` does not have those views the initialization fails.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
TextView text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myText);  
Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myButton);

return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. It works perfectly.

However, may I know the different between onCreate() and onCreateView()?

Answer (score 0):

try use **findViewById(R.id.myText);** not super.findViewById(R.id.myText);

and make sure you are using the right layout, if you are using **R.layout.activity_main** then your layout must be **activity_main.xml**

Comment: This makes no difference.

Comment: will do nothing if its fragment,,, this one is if you are using Activity.... if Fragment, call it on onCreateView and use the root view from inflater instead.. so it ll become: view.findViewById(...);

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, there's a bunch of weird/wrong things in your code, maybe they'll end up being a cause:

- Weird: calling `super.findViewById()` is redundant and you should just call `findViewById` directly
- Wrong: You state that your file is called `fragment_main.xml`, and yet your code references `activity_main.xml`
- Question: What does your import line for `R` look like? Maybe you're referencing the wrong R